# how do I put Ubuntu onto my galaxy S5 Rooted?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-for-android

I'm looking for how you boot, or dual boot Ubuntu onto my galaxy s5. Or if I can? If so how?

Answer (score -2):

Unity 8 as default GUI only in april/2016.

http://mhall119.com/2014/10/unity-8-desktop/

With that Canonical able to finally achieve your goal of having a converged operating system, ie, the same system interface (and code) will be used in both smartphones and tablets as on PCs.

You can try now for your own risk.